# Reboot issues when plugging other devices into power

Tags: power-supply, boot-issues

Model: Raspberry Pi 3b+
Raspberry pi 4.19.66-v7+
Raspbian Buster July 2019 edition
Offical PSU.
I have an Arduino uno powering off one of the USB ports on the PI. Nothing else attached.

I have my raspberry pi plugged into the official USB PSU which plugs into the mains power through a powerboard or through the wall socket. If I plug anything into one of the other power sockets or any of the free sockets on the powerboard the raspberry pi reboots. I thought it was a faulty PSU so I tested another official PSU. It still has the same problem. I've tried other sockets and powerboards around the house. Same problem. If I have any of the other devices plugged in and then turn the raspberry pi on it continues to function as normal. It only reboots when I plug one of these devices in after the raspberry pi is on. I've tried a number of different devices, all-cause it to reboot.

Regards
Dylan

Comment: To clarify, the Pi is rebooting when you plug something else into the mains? Does this still happen if you plug something else in in a different room?

Comment: @Fred-  from the question: "I've tried other sockets and powerboards around the house. Same problem."

Comment: Sounds like a household power problem to me. Faulty GFCI maybe.

Comment: I've tried different circuits around the house. I'm going to try a friends house and see if it happens there. I don't seem to have any issues with other appliances restarting like my main computer for example.